# Android Firebase search by child not calling onDataChange

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm currently creating a method to search my Firebase database by username. My `users/` structure looks like this:

```
uid : {
    displayName:value,
    email:value,
    otherUserData...
}
```

Which works great for searching if I have the uid of the user I'm searching for, but I want the users to be able to search for other accounts by account name because searching by UID would be ridiculous. Currently, I'm attempting to do this by using this method:

```
public void getUserByUsername(String username, final DatabaseCallback c) {
    Log.d(TAG, "getByUsername");
    DatabaseReference userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
    Query query = userRef.orderByChild("displayName").equalTo(username);
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot user : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Found user " + dataSnapshot.getValue());
                User u = user.getValue(User.class);
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "No user found");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Cancelled");
        }
    });
}
```

When I call this method, the first `Log.d` call goes through, but neither of the `Log.d` calls inside onDataChange get made. Thoughts?

Comment: use query.addValueEvent.. instead of userRef.addValueEvent...

Comment: *facepalm*. Still doesn't work though

Comment: isnide the for loop, you will want user.getValue(..) instead of dataSnapshot.getValue()

Comment: *double facepalm* although that didn't really matter because the `Log.d(TAG, "No user found");` still isn't called

Comment: so which one is it now, in the question you say "Found user.. " never gets called, and now "No user found" never gets called. Do neither get called?

Comment: If `onDataChange` isn't called, the most common case is that you're not connected.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, I updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was being denied permission to read, and as a result `onDataChange()` wasn't being called but `onCancelled()` was. I discovered this by putting a `Log.d()` call in my `onCancelled()` method